# Trigger key functionality works, but fails the test

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing the drum machine assignment on FreeCodeCamp. One of the requirements is to assign a trigger key (e.g. "Q") to a clickable element (e.g. ) on the DOM, so that it plays the sound inside the  element, which is a child element of the clickable element. It works as they ask (or so I think) but it fails the **test**.

For example: When I press "Q" on my keyboard, it should play the "heater-1" sound, which it does. But it fails the test.

Here's the link for the test: [User Story #6](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/front-end-development-libraries/front-end-development-libraries-projects/build-a-drum-machine)

Here's my code snippet:

```
  window.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    if (["q", "w", "e", "a", "s", "d", "z", "x", "c"].includes(e.key)) {
      // debugger;
      for (const obj of drumSounds) {
        if (obj.keyLabel === e.key.toUpperCase()) {
          let button = document.getElementById(obj.id);
          button.click();
          setTextToDisplay(obj.keyLabel);
          return;
        }
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <div id="drum-machine" className="App">
      <Display displayText={textToDisplay} />
      <div id="drum-pad-container">
        {drumSounds.map((obj) => (
          <DrumPad
            audioSource={obj.src}
            audioId={obj.keyLabel}
            key={obj.keyLabel}
            drumPadId={obj.id}
            keyLabel={obj.keyLabel}
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.target.children[0].play();
              setTextToDisplay(obj.keyLabel);
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this, and the issue was that I have written my code to check the "key" of the key pressed, instead of the "key code", so the test failed on when the key was uppercase. When I changed it to check for the key code, it worked fine.

Found the solution here : https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/build-a-drum-machine-user-story-6/243889